# Firebase Functions Trigger on Account Link

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to store email information on user documents when a user is created. For standard users who use email and password to sign up, I can simply call `auth.user().onCreate` and set the email on the user document. For users who sign in anonymously, and then later link their email, how can I get the email set on the user document? Is there a way to do this with Firestore triggers only? Does a `user().onUpdate` function exist? I want to avoid client side code that updates user documents.

Comment: There is no trigger when an account is linked (or updated in general). I'd recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 3):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no trigger when an account is linked (or updated in general). I'd recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to weigh in.

Comment: Any news about feature request?

Comment: Please file a feature request if you also desire this functionality. I am also in need of it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this.

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  if(!user.isAnonymous){
    //create an instance in firestore
    // ... 
  }
});
```